# Problem with Mediatek MT7630E and kernel 4.4

Tags: wifi, drivers, internet, hardware

I recently bought an Asus X554LA laptop, on which Freya works flawlessly.
Unfortunately the internal wifi board (Mediatek MT7630E) is not supported on Linux, there are some unofficial drivers but I failed to install them.

If I run "sudo lshw -C network" the output I get is:
`*-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 1c:b7:2c:96:2f:65
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7104000-f7104fff memory:f7100000-f7103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7000000-f70fffff`

In order to make the chipset work I tried to update the kernel (I am currently running 4.4.1-040401-generic). I also tried to install this unofficial driver [link](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E) (and other versions of it as well) but when I launch "./install" I get an error mentioning `-fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler` (I won't post the whole output because it cointains a lot of backticks and mess up the markdown layout).

As a workaround I tried to use a wifi dongle (Edimax EW-7811Un) which worked fine once I installed the drivers, but its antenna has a very short range, so overall it's not a viable solution.

Do anybody know a solution to install the driver?

Comment: That wifi card is certified by Ubuntu in some laptops: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci/14c3%3A7630/ . Can you copy and paste the results of the command "sudo lshw - C network"?

Comment: I couldn't really figure how to post code-formatted test, so I took a screenshot instead [link](https://db.tt/TENOsT8W).  

It seems like the system does recognize the hardware, but doesn't know how to get it to work properly.

Comment: You can edit your question and add code with the preformatted text tag, marked with {}.

About your issue, I can see a "network UNCLAIMED" line. This means that your system doesn't load any driver for this card. Try in terminal with the command:

modprobe rt2x00pci .

Comment the output.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway if I run the modprobe command nothing happens, and the output of lshw -C network is the same

Comment: There are some modificated drivers. I suposse you're running kernel 3.19, isn't it? If you don't know, try in terminal : uname -a

Comment: You should try https://github.com/benjarobin/MT7630E.  It has a compiled driver for kernel 4.4 28 days ago. Try installing rt2x00 driver

Comment: Copying the files in the folder "firmware" to "/lib/firmware" and rebooting did not work, but maybe I am missing something

Comment: Go to rt2x00 folder, open a terminal and try:  make && sudo make install && sudo modprobe mt7630e

Comment: the make command fails because of:  
`Makefile:660: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler  
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’`

Comment: Your kernel versión 4.4 expect to be compiled with gcc version 5, which is not by default on Freya. Version 5 and above support fstack-protector. You can install it from ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test.

Comment: Okay, once I installed gcc 5 the "make" command succeeds, but "make install" returns something like "No rule to generate the target "install" " (I get it written in Italian, so it might be not the exact translation)

Comment: Try reinstalling your headers with: "sudo apt-get install --reinstall git linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms" . Before this, you must do  "make" and "sudo make install" again.

Comment: Nope, I get the same output

Comment: There are some missing files to compile it. Try with other driver that the author has actualized to kernel 4.4: https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E

Comment: Glad to read it drgeppo. I answer your question in a summary to help others

Comment: Please consider to edit your question text. Currently, it's a mess of different questions which are not related at all (you ask how to install the driver, which model people could recommdend *and* which usb dongle could recommend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mediatek MT7630E driver with kernel 4.4 support**

In order to compile a new driver, you must open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

In elementary OS Freya you must install too the new gcc compiler. Open a terminal and write:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install g++-5
```

Now you can try to download the driver from the zip source at:

[neurobin github.com](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E)

and unzipped it, or you just clone it with git in a terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
```

After download, you must enter in the new created folder. Open the file README.md and follow instructions to install the new driver.