# how do I install Mediatek MT7630E Wifi driver for elementary loki

Tags: wifi

I have only just got elementary Loki and am brand new to linux. When Installed elementary onto my ASUS TP500L laptop the wifi didn't work. I saw another question for the same wifi driver[Problem with mediatek MT7630E and kernel 4.4 1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/problem-with-mediatek-mt7630e-and-kernel-4-4). I tried to follow it's steps but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

To install the Mediatek MT7630E Wifi driver on elementary , you should follow the steps described on the [github repo](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E)  :

You need to disable the secure boot from the BIOS settings then connect to the internet. Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
cd MT7630E/
chmod +x install test uninstall
sudo ./install
```

Comment: I have confirmed GAD3R's solution works. thanks.